# Excel Macro selects entire table rows, cuts and pastes to another table, then deletes original rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will do the following:

1. Recognize my active cell(s) and select the entire table row(s) of
   those cell(s). Cut all of those rows.
2. Paste them into another table on a different worksheet (at the end
   of the table to add on to whatever is already there).
3. Return to the original worksheet and delete the now empty rows.

I have a decent understanding of VBA. I was able to select the entire row based on my active cell. But if I select multiple cells (eg, B4, B5, and B6), it would only select one row instead of all three. Additionally, I've been having trouble getting it to select only the Table Row, not the entire Row.

This is the first line of code I started out with. But it doesn't A: Select multiple rows or B: Select only the row cells of the table.

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Even just help on part of the above steps could help me.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have code, you should include it. Don't make us guess what the issue is...

Comment: `Selection.EntireRow.Select` There's only one ActiveCell in the current selection.  When you say "table" do you mean Table as in an actual Excel Table object (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx), or just a set of data?

Comment: Yeah, an actual Excel Table. Something created from the "Format as Table" menu in the ribbon. I'd rather be able to select just the cells in the row that are in the table, and none of the other cells of that row.

Comment: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp might be useful - exactly how you'd approach it depends on whether that's the only table on the sheet or not. If there are other tables you'd need to loop through them and look at the intersection of the selection and each of the table ranges to find the "parent" table.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Lots of good info here. Luckily each of my worksheets only have one table. ".ListRows(4).Range.Select" looks like what I need, but I need to figure out how to use it to use my active selection and not a predetermined row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, _
                    Selection.Parent.ListObjects(1).Range)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'rng.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'do something with rng
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ran this through Excel and it doesn't seem to do anything with my selection.

Comment: As is, it doesn't do anything - it was intended to help you figure out how to select whole rows from your table...